# Laravel 6.3.0 + Apache2 - Connection is reset after the kernel loads

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

I am having a seemingly unsolvable problem with a recent installation of Laravel. Laravel is installed properly and runs fine with the PHP server but when I want to load it in apache on localhost:80, the **connection is reset** after the following call in the index.php file.

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
  $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

The following function somehow resets the http connection and I get a reset connection http error. This does not happen when I try to load an unmapped url, I get a 404 error and laravel runs properly.
[image]

I followed the installation guide and all dependencies are installed.
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation

The apache error log says a process is forked and then sigterm:

```
  cat /var/log/apache2/error.log 
    [Wed Oct 16 16:02:18.007501 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 56037] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
    **[Wed Oct 16 16:02:18.024221 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 56037] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d PHP/7.3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations**
    [Wed Oct 16 16:02:18.024276 2019] [core:notice] [pid 56037] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/local/sbin/httpd'
    [Wed Oct 16 16:04:52.053878 2019] [core:notice] [pid 56037] AH00052: child pid 56042 exit signal Bus error (10)
**[Wed Oct 16 16:29:33.693999 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 56037] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down**
```

I have many php sites running in my machine working fine with other frameworks.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Anything in the laravel log?

Comment: No, the laravel blog remains empty.

Comment: `$kernel->handle($request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());` will handle the entire request including all middleware etc. Does the request fail on all possible mapped routes? Does it also fail when you comment out all middleware (in Kernel.php) ?

Comment: Commenting the middleware works! Now I have to find out which one is failing.

Comment: The offending middleWare is \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, when commented out of the Web Middleware, everything works.

Comment: That's kind of an important middleware though (if you intend to use the session). Is your session configured correctly?

Comment: I just installed laravel, I have not coded any app yet. It is freshly installed. Yes, session is important for an App. I have to disable StartSession:class, AuthenticateSession:class, ShareErrorsFromSession:class and VerifyCSRToken:class. Else I get execution errors down the line.

Comment: Fix the version in the title, 6.6.3 is nonexistent version.